# PHP image upload

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to upload an image to server using PHP and save inside a dir, and then returning the image url.

html code:

```
 <form method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP code for upload image:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Save']))
    {
     /*image */
     $traget_dir="image/";
     $traget_file=$traget_dir .basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
     $uploadOk=1;
     $imageFileType = pathinfo($traget_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $check=getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
     } else{
        echo "File is not an image.";
       $uploadOk = 0;
     }
     /*end image upload*/
    }
    ?>
```

error on upload time:

> Notice: Undefined index: image in

second error->

> Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be
>   empty in

thank for help and view.

Comment: can you show your full php code and html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this action after submit and check with if condition like following code.
where 'SUBMIT' is the name of your button.

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
{
 /*image */
 $traget_dir="image/";
 $traget_file=$traget_dir .basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $uploadOk=1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($traget_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $check=getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
 } else{
    echo "File is not an image.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 /*end image upload*/
}
```

Comment: You've to add this in your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: like `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you have to check mime-type and extension also, and the best practice is to upload your files in `/year/month/file` to avoid file system problems, take a look at this code https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/SimpleUploader

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the form that its also going to be uploading files.

You can do this by using `enctype=multipart/form-data`

So, your form should look like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `

```
<form method="post">
```

with this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and you are all good to go :)